# Very slow scripts (with weird errors) after a recovery of a previous version of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: weir erros]

I was having problems with a spreadsheet, and I decided to go back to a previous version...

However, I noticed that after this restoration, the spreadsheet SCRIPTS were SUPER SLOW (often shutting down by timeout) and presenting errors that I've never seen! (like the ones I posted above). It's like the script is having a hard time finding the spreadsheet...

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? I've tried everything!

Look at this simple script, which starts quickly, but on the first line it takes 2 MINUTES to perform!!! (Full script after screenshot)

[image: simple script taking 2 minutes to "start"]

Script:

```
    function atualizarDisparos() {
Logger.log("step1")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DB'); 
Logger.log("step2")
  
 
  var startRow = 27; // Lembrar de tirar o cabeçalho
  var quantidadeDeViveiros = 16;
  var lastRow = startRow + quantidadeDeViveiros; // figure out what the last row is

  Logger.log("step4")

  var startColumn = 2; // Lembrar de tirar as bordas
  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn(); // figure out what the last column is
  var numColumns = lastColumn-startColumn+1; // subtrair um pelo outro

  var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, quantidadeDeViveiros, numColumns)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var povoamento ="";
  var bioensaio ="";
  var despesca ="";
  var povoadoHoje ="";
  var atualizar = 0;

  var biomassaDespesca = 2000;
  var tamanhoDespesca = 18;
  var tempoBioensaio = 3;
  var diasParaVenda = 15;

Logger.log("step4")

  for (var linhaAtual = 0; linhaAtual <= quantidadeDeViveiros-1; linhaAtual++) {
    var row = data[linhaAtual];
    Logger.log("step5")
    if (row[7] == 0 || row[35] < diasParaVenda) { //==== POVOAMENTO
      var povoamento = povoamento + "V" + row[0] + " (" + row[12] + "kg de " + row[14] + "g) || "
      var atualizar = 1;
    } 

    if (row[7] != 0 && row[9] == "" && row[11] <= 3) { //=== BIOENSAIO
      var dataPovoamento = new Date(row[5]);
      var dataBioensaio = dataPovoamento.setDate(dataPovoamento.getDate()+tempoBioensaio-1);
      var dataBioensaio = new Date(dataBioensaio);
      var dataHoje = new Date();
      Logger.log(dataBioensaio)
      Logger.log(dataHoje)      

      if (dataHoje >= dataBioensaio) {
        var dataBioensaio = Utilities.formatDate(dataBioensaio, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yy');
        var bioensaio = bioensaio + "V" + row[0] + " (Tirar Bioensaio: " + dataBioensaio + ") || "
      }
      var atualizar = 1;
    } 

      if (row[7] != 0 && row[8] == 0) { //=== POVOADO HOJE
      var dataPovoamento = new Date(row[5]);
      var dataPovoamento = new Date(dataPovoamento);
      var dataPovoamento = Utilities.formatDate(dataPovoamento, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yy');
      var povoadoHoje = povoadoHoje + "V" + row[0] + " (Povoado dia: " + dataPovoamento + ") || "

      var atualizar = 1;
    } 

    if (row[14] >= 8 && row[35] < diasParaVenda) { //=== DESPESCA
      var despesca = despesca + "V" + row[0] + " (" + row[12] + "kg de " + row[14] + "g) || "
      var atualizar = 1
    }
  }

  if(atualizar == 1) {
    var ssPC = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PC'); 
    ssPC.getRange('k107').setValue(povoamento);
    ssPC.getRange('k108').setValue(bioensaio);
    ssPC.getRange('k109').setValue(despesca);
    ssPC.getRange('k123').setValue(povoadoHoje);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the script bound to the spreadsheet that cannot be accessed?

Comment: Yea! I created the script from the spreadsheet, and I never took it out again...

Even the scripts are working! However, VERY slow, to the point of time out!

Is there any way to unlink and relink?

Comment: Try to make a copy of the current spreadsheet (which will make a copy of the script). If the copy  is still slow, probably your spreadsheet is very heavy (many sheets, formulas, images etc.)

Comment: All of your current usage of getValues() should be replaced with getValue() because you are only asking for one value in your range. However none of this would provide a reason to slow the code down as much as you explain.

Comment: Have you checked that the document Id is shown in the error message still exists? It's pretty weird that it's not recognizing the file if it indeed exists.

Comment: Yes there is, Gabriel! It's the original spreadsheet that I'm running the script on! Strange right?